# Polylines are not showing between 2 Locations but Time and Distance is showing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

**Note: Sorry for my bad English because English is not my native language I have used Google Translate for this.**

I am working on an Android map app in which a user can find their friends' current location. For storing the current location I am using Firebase real time database. With previous help of Lalit Singh it is showing time and distance now but  still not updating the Polylines between 2 different places. My updates code is below.

mapsActivity.java (where i am getting friend location from fire base and updated time, distance and polylines method called)

> ```
>   public void proceed(final View view) {
>
>     DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Email");
>
>     ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>             for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
>                 UserInformation details = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserInformation.class);
>
>                 if (mMap != null) {
>                     mMap.clear();
>                 }
>
>                 MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
>                 LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(details.getLatitude(), details.getLongitude());
>                 markerOptions.position(latLng1);
>                 markerOptions.title(String.valueOf(latLng1));
>                 mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
>                 mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
>                 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng1));
>                 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
>
>                 distance_task.getDirectionsUrl(latLng1, markerOptions.getPosition());
>                 distance_task.setLoadListener(new CalculateDistanceTime.taskCompleteListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void taskCompleted(String[] time_distance) {
>                         text1.setText(time_distance[0]); //Distance
>                         text2.setText(time_distance[1]); //Time
>                     }
>                 });
>
>                 String url = getDirectionsUrl(latLng1, markerOptions.getPosition());
>                 DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
>                 downloadTask.execute(url);
>             }
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

CalculateDistanceTime.java (added new Class)

> ```
> class CalculateDistanceTime {     private taskCompleteListener
> mTaskListener; private Context mContext;      
> CalculateDistanceTime(Context context) {
> mContext = context; }     void setLoadListener(taskCompleteListener taskListener) {
> mTaskListener = taskListener; }        void getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
>
> // Origin of route
> String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
>
> // Destination of route
> String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
>
>
> // Sensor enabled
> String sensor = "sensor=false";
>
> // Building the parameters to the web service
> String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;
>
> // Output format
> String output = "json";
>
> // Building the url to the web service
> String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
>
>
> DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
>
> // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
>
> downloadTask.execute(url); }
>
> private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
> String data = "";
> HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
> URL url = new URL(strUrl);
>
> // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
> urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>
> // Connecting to url
> urlConnection.connect();
>
> // Reading data from url
> try (InputStream iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
>     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
>
>     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>
>     String line;
>     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
>         sb.append(line);
>     }
>
>     data = sb.toString();
>
>     br.close();
>
> } catch (Exception e) {
>     Log.d("Excp. while downloading", e.toString());
> } finally {
>     urlConnection.disconnect();
> }
> return data; }
>
> interface taskCompleteListener {
> void taskCompleted(String[] time_distance); }
>
> private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
>
> // Downloading data in non-ui thread
> @Override
> protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
>
>     // For storing data from web service
>     String data = "";
>
>     try {
>         // Fetching the data from web service
>         data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
>     }
>     return data;
> }
>
> // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
> // doInBackground()
> @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>     super.onPostExecute(result);
>
>     ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
>
>     // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
>     parserTask.execute(result);
>
> } }
>
> private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer,
> List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
>
> // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
> @Override
> protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
>
>     JSONObject jObject;
>     List<HashMap<String, String>> routes = null;
>
>     try {
>         jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
>         DistanceTimeParser parser = new DistanceTimeParser();
>
>         // Starts parsing data
>         routes = parser.parse(jObject);
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     return routes;
> }
>
> // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
> @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
>
>     String duration_distance = "";
>
>
>     if (result.size() < 1) {
>         Log.e("Error : ", "No Points found");
>         return;
>     }
>
>
>     String[] date_dist = new String[2];
>
>     // Traversing through all the routes
>     for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
>
>         // Fetching i-th route
>         HashMap<String, String> tmpData = result.get(i);
>         Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
>         Iterator it = key.iterator();
>         while (it.hasNext()) {
>             String hmKey = (String) it.next();
>             duration_distance = tmpData.get(hmKey);
>
>             System.out.println("Key: " + hmKey + " & Data: " + duration_distance);
>
>             it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
>         }
>
>         date_dist[i] = duration_distance;
>     }
>
>     mTaskListener.taskCompleted(date_dist);
> }   } }
> ```

DistanceTimeParser.java (added new class)

> ```
> public class DistanceTimeParser {
> public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {
>
>
>     List<HashMap<String, String>> routes = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
>     JSONArray jRoutes = null;
>     JSONArray jLegs = null;
>
>     JSONObject jDistance = null;
>     JSONObject jDuration = null;
>
>     try {
>
>         jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
>
>         jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(0)).getJSONArray("legs");
>
>         List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
>
>
>         /** Getting distance from the json data */
>         jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(0)).getJSONObject("distance");
>         HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
>         hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));
>
>         /** Getting duration from the json data */
>         jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(0)).getJSONObject("duration");
>         HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
>         hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));
>
>         routes.add(hmDistance);
>
>         routes.add(hmDuration);
>
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>     }
>
>     return routes;
> } }
> ```

DirectionsJSONParser.java (added new class)

> ```
> public class DirectionsJSONParser {
>
> List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){
>
>     List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>() ;
>     JSONArray jRoutes ;
>     JSONArray jLegs ;
>     JSONArray jSteps ;
>
>     try {
>
>         jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
>
>
>         for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
>             jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
>             List path = new ArrayList<>();
>
>             for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
>                 jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
>
>
>                 for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
>                     String polyline;
>                     polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
>                     List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
>
>
>                     for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
>                         HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
>                         hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude) );
>                         hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude) );
>                         path.add(hm);
>                     }
>                 }
>                 routes.add(path);
>             }
>         }
>
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }catch (Exception ignored){
>     }
>
>     return routes;
> }
>
> private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
>
>     List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
>     int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
>     int lat = 0, lng = 0;
>
>     while (index < len) {
>         int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
>         do {
>             b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
>             result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
>             shift += 5;
>         } while (b >= 0x20);
>         int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
>         lat += dlat;
>
>         shift = 0;
>         result = 0;
>         do {
>             b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
>             result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
>             shift += 5;
>         } while (b >= 0x20);
>         int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
>         lng += dlng;
>
>         LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
>                 (((double) lng / 1E5)));
>         poly.add(p);
>     }
>
>     return poly;
> } }
> ```

These 4 methods added in mapsActivity.java

> ```
>   private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
>
>     String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
>
>     String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
>
>     String sensor = "sensor=false";
>
>     String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;
>
>     String output = "json";
>
>     return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
> }
>
>   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
>   public static String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
>     String data = "";
>     HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
>     URL url = new URL(strUrl);
>
>     // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
>     urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>
>     // Connecting to url
>     urlConnection.connect();
>
>     // Reading data from url
>     try (InputStream iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
>         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
>
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>
>         String line;
>         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
>             sb.append(line);
>         }
>
>         data = sb.toString();
>
>         br.close();
>
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Log.d("Exception while down", e.toString());
>     } finally {
>         urlConnection.disconnect();
>     }
>     return data;
> }
>
>   private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
>
>     // Downloading data in non-ui thread
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
>
>         // For storing data from web service
>         String data = "";
>
>         try {
>             // Fetching the data from web service
>             data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
>         }
>         return data;
>     }
>
>     // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
>     // doInBackground()
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>         super.onPostExecute(result);
>
>         ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
>
>         // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
>         parserTask.execute(result);
>     }
> }
>
> private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {
>
>     @Override
>     protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
>
>         JSONObject jObject;
>         List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
>
>         try {
>             jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
>             DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
>
>             // Starts parsing data
>             routes = parser.parse(jObject);
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         return routes;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
>         ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
>         PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
>         for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
>             List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
>             for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
>                 HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
>                 double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
>                 double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
>                 LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
>                 points.add(position);
>             }
>             lineOptions.addAll(points);
>             lineOptions.width(10);
>             lineOptions.color(Color.WHITE);
>             mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

mapsActivity.java (my current location in map)

> ```
> @Override
> public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
>     Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");
>
>     mLastLocation = location;
>
>     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
>     dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
>     Date date = new Date();
>     mLastUpdateTime = ((dateFormat.format(date).toString()));
>
>     saveToFirebase();
>
>     if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
>         mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
>     }
>
>     latitude = location.getLatitude();
>     longitude = location.getLongitude();
>
>     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
>     MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
>     markerOptions.position(latLng);
>     markerOptions.draggable(false);
>     markerOptions.title("Current Position");
>     markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
>     mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
>
>     //move map camera
>     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
>     mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
>
>     Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
>     //stop location updates
>     if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
>      LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
>    this);
>         Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
>     }
> }
> ```

Data Saved in Fire Base Method

> ```
> public void saveToFirebase() {
>
>     DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Email").push();
>     String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
>     UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(email, mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
>     ref.setValue(userInformation);
> }
> ```

Comment: Your `DataParser.parseDirections` method is wrong, it takes into consideration only the first `step` of the first `leg`. There may be other problems but that is what is most evident to me.

Comment: @Titus Before this i really didn't work on maps and have watched tons of tutorials on youtube and created this but now i don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar using separate class because in mapsActivity.java other functions also available like nearby hospitals, schools etc and watched on youtube tutorial and created the separate class. I think it is easy way to call in different methods.

Comment: You can start by trying to understand what the code does. The `DataParser` class seems to be used to process the response JSON from Google Maps Directions API. You can find the format of that JSON [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) What you'll need to do is to extract all the coordinates from all the `steps` in all the `legs` of a `route` and use them to create a polyline.

Comment: @Titus i have updated the code which i missed.

Comment: @AmitRana How can you really expect polyline to be there when you're passing the same values? First you set `markerOptions.position(latlng1)` then you place the method call as `String url = getDirectionsUrl(latLng1, markerOptions.getPosition());`. Don't you think markerOptions's value is latlng1 as you set it. So basically both the positions are same.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar got it and understandable your point, so where i need to change the CurrentLocation which is store latlng, latlng detects my current location. Should i replace in markerOptions or getDirectionsUrl?

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar i have updated my current location code which is also in mapsActivity.java.. But i am unable to paste all java file because code is too long and stackoverflow restricted to paste long code.

Comment: This is what you should do : `String url = getDirectionsUrl(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()),latLng1);`.

Comment: i have updated this code but still not polylines is showing. And when i delete this code distance_task.getDirectionsUrl(latLng1, markerOptions.getPosition()); polyline is showing but Time and Distance is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you need Route, Distance and Time.
First Create these 3 classes.

1. CalculateDistanceTime.java

   ```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.util.Log;    
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;    
   import org.json.JSONObject;    
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Set;    
   class CalculateDistanceTime {    
   private taskCompleteListener mTaskListener;
   private Context mContext;      
   CalculateDistanceTime(Context context) {
       mContext = context;
   }    
   void setLoadListener(taskCompleteListener taskListener) {
       mTaskListener = taskListener;
   }       
   void getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

       // Origin of route
       String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

       // Destination of route
       String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


       // Sensor enabled
       String sensor = "sensor=false";

       // Building the parameters to the web service
       String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

       // Output format
       String output = "json";

       // Building the url to the web service
       String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


       DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

       // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API

       downloadTask.execute(url);
   }

   private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
       String data = "";
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
       URL url = new URL(strUrl);

       // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
       urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

       // Connecting to url
       urlConnection.connect();

       // Reading data from url
       try (InputStream iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

           String line;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line);
           }

           data = sb.toString();

           br.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d("Excp. while downloading", e.toString());
       } finally {
           urlConnection.disconnect();
       }
       return data;
   }


   interface taskCompleteListener {
       void taskCompleted(String[] time_distance);
   }

   private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

       // Downloading data in non-ui thread
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

           // For storing data from web service
           String data = "";

           try {
               // Fetching the data from web service
               data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
           }
           return data;
       }

       // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
       // doInBackground()
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);

           ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

           // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
           parserTask.execute(result);

       }
   }

   private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

       // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
       @Override
       protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

           JSONObject jObject;
           List<HashMap<String, String>> routes = null;

           try {
               jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
               DistanceTimeParser parser = new DistanceTimeParser();

               // Starts parsing data
               routes = parser.parse(jObject);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return routes;
       }

       // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

           String duration_distance = "";


           if (result.size() < 1) {
               Log.e("Error : ", "No Points found");
               return;
           }


           String[] date_dist = new String[2];

           // Traversing through all the routes
           for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {

               // Fetching i-th route
               HashMap<String, String> tmpData = result.get(i);
               Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
               Iterator it = key.iterator();
               while (it.hasNext()) {
                   String hmKey = (String) it.next();
                   duration_distance = tmpData.get(hmKey);

                   System.out.println("Key: " + hmKey + " & Data: " + duration_distance);

                   it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
               }

               date_dist[i] = duration_distance;
           }

           mTaskListener.taskCompleted(date_dist);
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. DistanceTimeParser.java

   ```
   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;

   public class DistanceTimeParser {
       public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {


       List<HashMap<String, String>> routes = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       JSONArray jRoutes = null;
       JSONArray jLegs = null;

       JSONObject jDistance = null;
       JSONObject jDuration = null;

       try {

           jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

           jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(0)).getJSONArray("legs");

           List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


           /** Getting distance from the json data */
           jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(0)).getJSONObject("distance");
           HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
           hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

           /** Getting duration from the json data */
           jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(0)).getJSONObject("duration");
           HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
           hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

           routes.add(hmDistance);

           routes.add(hmDuration);

       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (Exception e) {
       }

       return routes;
   }
   }
   ```
3. DirectionsJSONParser.java

   ```
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;    
   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;    
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;
   class DirectionsJSONParser {


   List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

       List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>() ;
       JSONArray jRoutes ;
       JSONArray jLegs ;
       JSONArray jSteps ;

       try {

           jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");


           for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
               jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
               List path = new ArrayList<>();

               for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                   jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");


                   for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                       String polyline;
                       polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                       List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);


                       for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                           HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                           hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude) );
                           hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude) );
                           path.add(hm);
                       }
                   }
                   routes.add(path);
               }
           }

       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch (Exception ignored){
       }

       return routes;
   }

   private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

       List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
       int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
       int lat = 0, lng = 0;

       while (index < len) {
           int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
           do {
               b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
               result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
               shift += 5;
           } while (b >= 0x20);
           int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
           lat += dlat;

           shift = 0;
           result = 0;
           do {
               b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
               result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
               shift += 5;
           } while (b >= 0x20);
           int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
           lng += dlng;

           LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                   (((double) lng / 1E5)));
           poly.add(p);
       }

       return poly;
   }
   }
   ```

After simply copying these three files.
What you can do is the following for any MapsActivity.
This is the point where you can use below code in any activity and above code will remain same for every acitivity(Maps for Directions).
 
Create a global variable `CalculateDistanceTime distance_task;`.
Initialize it in the `onCreate` as `distance_task = new CalculateDistanceTime(this);`

Post this 4 methods in your MapsActivity.java.

```
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;


        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


        String sensor = "sensor=false";


        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        String output = "json";


        return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
    }

    public static String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        try (InputStream iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while down", e.toString());
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    points.add(position);
                }
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(10);                   
                lineOptions.color(Color.WHITE);
                googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);                
        }
    }
```

At this point you have all the needed code.
Now use the following code passing the latlngs of your location and friend's location and you'll have Time Distance and Route.:

```
               distance_task.getDirectionsUrl(latLng1, latLng2);
               distance_task.setLoadListener(new CalculateDistanceTime.taskCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void taskCompleted(String[] time_distance) {
                            text1.setText(time_distance[0]); //Distance
                            text2.setText(time_distance[1]); //Time
                        }
                    });
               String url = getDirectionsUrl(latLng1, latLng2);
               DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
               downloadTask.execute(url);
```

For displaying Distance and Time, You have to create two `TextView` (see text1 and Text2 above).

Comment: thanks for detail answer but i am getting an error on destMarker in red and i don't know what is this and from it comes, also red error on v1.setVisibility(View.Visible) v1 also in red. Kindly help to explain these 2 things also. thanks

Comment: okay i have remove the v1 line and replaced the destMarker with markerOptions in my project, kindly guide me have i replaced this correctly?

Comment: now it is showing time and distance but no polylines on map, kindly help on this.

Comment: i need to update the code in main question or pasted here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157065/discussion-between-amit-rana-and-lalit-singh-fauzdar).

Answer (score 0):

Add below code and replace with your drawing polylines code, Use this

```
 String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
 FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();

 // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
FetchUrl.execute(url);
```

Use above code where you want to draw directions, `origin` & `dest` are LatLng object for example below,

```
LatLng dest = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(d_lat), Double.parseDouble(d_lng));
```

Here are the following methods to get directions,

```
private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service


        return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
    }
```

After this use these below classes,

```
private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                Log.d("Background Task data", data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                Log.d("ParserTask", jsonData[0]);

                JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                JSONObject paths = array.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray legs = paths.getJSONArray("legs");
                JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
                JSONObject duration = legs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("duration");
                parsedDistance = distance.getString("text");
                if (parsedDistance.contains("km")) {
                    String[] val = parsedDistance.split(" ");
                    String val1 = val[0];
                    distance_from = convertInMiles(val1);
                } else {
                    distance_from = parsedDistance;
                }
                address = legs.getJSONObject(0).getString("end_address");
                time = duration.getString("text");
                DataParser parser = new DataParser();
                Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                Log.d("ParserTask", "Executing routes");
                Log.d("ParserTask", routes.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ParserTask", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            if (result != null && result.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    points = new ArrayList<>();
                    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                    // Fetching i-th route
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                    // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                    for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                        points.add(position);
                    }

                    // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                    lineOptions.addAll(points);
                    lineOptions.width(10);
                    lineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);

                    p_distance.setText("Distance : " + distance_from);
                    p_time.setText("ETA :" + time);
                    if (p_time.getText().toString().length() == 10) {
                        arrival_time = p_time.getText().toString().substring(5, p_time.getText().toString().length() - 4);
                        Log.d("arrival_time", arrival_time);
                        SessionManager.put(Constants.TIME, arrival_time);
                    } else if (p_time.getText().toString().length() > 10) {
                        arrival_time = p_time.getText().toString().substring(5, p_time.getText().toString().length() - 5);
                        Log.d("arrival_time", arrival_time);
                        SessionManager.put(Constants.TIME, arrival_time);
                    }
                    p_address.setText("Address : " + address);
                    navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.d("onPostExecute", "onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");
                }

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            if (lineOptions != null) {
                mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            } else {
                Log.d("onPostExecute", "without Polylines drawn");
            }
        }
    }

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            Log.d("downloadUrl", data);
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            assert iStream != null;
            iStream.close();
            assert urlConnection != null;
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply but please guide me where i need to paste this code because i am new in android and i have created this with the help of tutorial. It will be great and helpful for me if you guide me that where i need to put above code.