# Google Maps put markers and show direction to selected one

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

What I want to achieve is the button which show direction after click. 
How should I place my markers? And what is the way to show the right way from my current position position shown by the navigator.

Here is my MapsActivity  in which I already declare some specific funtions I need.

```
   public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    Button logoutButton;

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View decor_View = getWindow().getDecorView();

        int ui_Options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        decor_View.setSystemUiVisibility(ui_Options);

        UiChangeListener();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);

        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    private void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }


        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.custom_google_map));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(51.1117744, 17.0353596))
                .title("Giselle French Bakery Cafe")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(20 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(20 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("You are here");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    public void UiChangeListener() {
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope someone could answer me how to achieve that :)

Comment: Please explain little more...you want to select marker and then you need a button to click on and it shows you distance.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not specified from where you want to display the directions but as you've implemented location in your java code, I'm assuming you want to show directions between your current Location and a clicked marker.

First, Go to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46825001/8244632) and create all those three java files required for distance, time and directions.

Then, Implement onMarkerClick in your program as follows:

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap){
    .
    .
    .
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    .
    .
    .
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        distance_task.getDirectionsUrl(latLng, marker.getPosition());
        distance_task.setLoadListener(new CalculateDistanceTime.taskCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void taskCompleted(String[] time_distance) {
                            text1.setText(time_distance[0]); //Distance
                            text2.setText(time_distance[1]); //Time
                        }
                    });
        String url = getDirectionsUrl(latLng, marker.getPosition());
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        downloadTask.execute(url);
    }
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

The above code will provide you the distance between those two points (yourLocation, Marker), time (taken using a car) and the polylines and implement the polylines by itself but do remember to pass the two `Textview` (text1 and text2) to set the distance and time else it will show error.

Also, if you want the directions only, then use only the DirectionsJSONParser.java and only the last three lines of above code in `onMarkerClick`.

This will work for sure as I'm using the same way but there are some additional things you have to consider for your app to run smoothly without crashing. Some of those problems are this code should only execute when mLastLocation is not null, when there is internet connectivity, when the GPS is turned on etc. Also, on clicking any other marker, the previous route should be removed etc.

**EDIT:** (Directly copied from my Project)
Declare two global variables

```
 Polyline lastPolyline;
 boolean isSecond = false;
```

Then in the onPostExecute() method in the class ParserTask:

replace `googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);` with

```
if (isSecond) {
   lastPolyline.remove();
   lastPolyline = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
   } 
else {
   lastPolyline = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
   isSecond = true;
   }
```

Comment: It looks really great. I will implement whole stuff as fast as I can, and answer is it works properly. But what about Google Direction ? Are u using it here ?

Comment: I encountered some problem. I am not sure how to define last three methods, and also i get a message that onMarkerClick should return statement. It would be really important for me if you find some time to  explain me this.

Comment: So is this illegal in this way as u show me at the top ? or it's legal if I just use polyline ? It's really matter in this way. And of course all works well, I change everything yesterday as I want so it it really great and proper solution !

Comment: So in the end this solution on the top is legal :) ?

Comment: And one last think ! how am I suppose to clear the direction to one marker if i click to another one ?

Comment: I am not sure if u understood what I am trying to achieve. If i click first marker it show me properly polyline way to find this marker on map. But when I click to another one, it show the polyline to new marker which is already set on map, but previous one is still shown. I want to delete every single previous one when I click another marker on map. And I am not sure where declare polyline variable, and for what assign it.

Comment: I have tried this kind of solution but it doesn't work
            if (isSecond) {
                polyline.remove();
                polyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            } else {
                polyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
                isSecond = true;
            }

but it never change properly for true

Comment: @Deisy You've tried the same solution, I didn't see it. I think you've not used global variables for this and that's why it's not working as required.